# What line of code would I need to find the monthTotal, monthAverage, and numDays?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
#Declare variables.
index = 0
monthName = ''
numDays = 0
monthTotal = 0
monthAverage = 0

try:
# Open inputFile with number of steps in it.
    infile = open('steps.txt', 'r')

# Read contents of file into variable stepsPerDay.
    stepsPerDay = infile.readlines()

    # Create list by stripping off the newline characters.
    for i in range(len(stepsPerDay)):
        stepsPerDay[i] = stepsPerDay[i].rstrip()

    print(stepsPerDay)


    # Create a dictionary named calendar that has
    # monthName as keys and the numDays (number of days in
    # the month) as values.
    calender = {'January':31}#, 'February':28, 'March':31, 'April':30, 'May':31, 'June':30, 'July':31, 'August':31, 'September':30, 'October':31, 'November':30, 'December':31}  

    # Loop through each month in year.  
    for monthName in calender:
        monthTotal = XXXXX
        monthAverage = XXXXXX
        numDays = XXXXX

        print(monthTotal)
        print(monthName)
        print(monthAverage)
```

I need to find the Month total, name, average, and the number of days a month. I can only change the XXXXX in the code because this is a fix-it exercise for school.
I need to figure out the amount of steps walked each day, the total of those steps per month, and the average of each month. The amount of steps is stored in a .txt file and I don't know what code to use in order to only take the required steps from where they're indexed in the list. I'm new to python programming and my professor hasn't been a lot of help as of this assignment.

Comment: I am not sure what's in that file but here is a possible solution: `monthTotal = int(stepsPerDay[index]) * calender[monthName]`
        `monthAverage = monthTotal/12`
       `numDays = calender[monthName]`

Comment: For homework questions, you really should show your own work before you ask. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the file `steps.txt` contains a number of steps for every day in the year and that your variable `index` is increased in your `for` loop, the code may be

```
for monthName in calender:
    monthTotal = sum(map(int, stepsPerDay[index: index + calender[monthName]]))
    monthAverage = monthTotal / calender[monthName]
    numDays = calender[monthName]
```